# If $\sigma(p^m)=2^n$ for prime $p$,then $m=1$ and $n$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Exercise from Beginning Number Theory by Neville Robbins:

> Let $\sigma(a)$ denote the sum of divisors of $a$.Then we have to prove that if $\sigma(p^m)=2^n$ for some prime $p$,then $m=1$ and $n$ is a prime.

The result does not hold for $p=2$.Now,$$\dfrac{p^{m+1}-1}{p-1}=2^n$$

$$\implies p^{m+1}-1=2^n(p-1)$$

Then,$$p^{m+1}\equiv 1\pmod {2^n}$$ and $$p^{m+1}\equiv 1\pmod {p-1}$$ I can't go anywhere from here.A hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excluding $m = 0$ - when $\sigma(p^0) = 2^0$ - we see that $p$ must be an odd prime, since $\sigma(2^m) \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$. So $\sigma(p^m) = 1 + p + \dotsc + p^m \equiv m+1 \pmod{2}$ forces $m$ to be odd. Then let $k = \frac{m+1}{2}$ in

$$\sigma(p^m) = \frac{p^{2k}-1}{p-1} = (p^k+1)\cdot\frac{p^k-1}{p-1}.$$

If $\sigma(p^m) = 2^n$, then $p^k+1 = 2^r$ and $\dfrac{p^k-1}{p-1} = 2^s$, where $r+s = n$ and $s < r$. Since $\gcd(p^k+1,p^k-1) = \gcd(p^k+1,2) = 2$, it follows that $s \leqslant 1$, and $\frac{p^k-1}{p-1} = 1 + p + \dotsc + p^{k-1} \leqslant 2$ then yields $k = 1$ and hence $m = 1$, so $p = 2^n-1$.

If $2^n-1$ is prime, then $n$ itself must be prime: $2^t-1$ is a nontrivial divisor of $2^{s\cdot t}-1$ for all $s,t > 1$, so $2^n-1$ is composite when $n$ is composite (and often also when $n$ is prime).

Comment: If the first factor is a power of 2,then $p$ must be 3 and k must be 1,and the first claim follows.Doesn't this mean that the only choice of p is 3?

Comment: No, we could have $p = 7,31,127,8191,\dotsc$ too. Both factors must be powers of $2$, and the point is to see that if $k > 1$, then only one can be a power of $2$ (consider the greatest common divisor of the two factors).

Comment: Let $p^k+1=2^m$.Then $p^k-1=2(2^{m-1}-1)$ which in turn implies that the second factor is $\dfrac{2(2^{m-1}-1)}{p-1}$ which implies that at least one factor of $p-1$ divides $2^{m-1}-1$.But since $p-1$ is even,that is impossible.Am I correct?

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand the last bit. As written, it's not correct, an even number can have factors dividing an odd number. I suspect however that you meant something a little different. Anyway, writing $p^k-1 = 2(2^{m-1}-1)$ is good. We know that $\frac{2(2^{m-1}-1)}{p-1}$ is a power of $2$, and we know that $p-1 = 2^a\cdot (2r+1)$ with $a \geqslant 1$ and $r\geqslant 0$. So $$\frac{2(2^{m-1}-1)}{2^a\cdot(2r+1)} = 2^j,$$ what does that tell you about $a$ and $2r+1$?

Comment: $2^{m-1}-1$ when divided by $2r+1$ cannot yield an even number,and hence the right side cannot be a power of $2$.

Comment: Well, it can be $2^0$. But that is indeed the only possibility, so we must have $a = 1$ and $2r+1 = 2^{m-1}-1$, or, in other words, $p-1 = p^k-1$.

Comment: Putting the value of m then yields $p=2^n-1$.Then $2^n\equiv 1\pmod p$.Then n must be divisible by the order of 2 mod p.I am unable to see why n must be prime.

Comment: If $n$ is not prime, $2^n-1$ is not prime. Can you write down a nontrivial divisor of $2^{s\cdot t}-1$ where $s,t > 1$?

Comment: $2^s-1$ and $2^t-1$.Thanks for the answer(not to mention replying to my comments).