# If $\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1} = 2^{a}$ then $n+1 = 2^{b}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Let $p>2$ prime, $n$ positive integer. Knowing $\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1} = 2^{a}$ for some $a\in \mathbb{N}$ show that $n+1$ is also a power of $2$.

To be honest I have no idea how to prove it. I know that $\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1} = 1 + p + p^{2} + ... + p^{n}$ so $n$ has to be odd. First few examples that work are $p=3, n=1$; $p=7, n=1$; $p=31, n=1$ so maybe $n$ has to be equal to $1$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\sigma(p^m)=2^n$ for prime $p$,then $m=1$ and $n$ is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748128/if-sigmapm-2n-for-prime-p-then-m-1-and-n-is-prime) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Bp%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D-1%7D%7Bp-1%7D%3D2%5E%7Ba%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24n%2B1%3D2%5Eb%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime&p=1). Note that $\sigma(p^n)=1+p+\ldots +p^{n}=\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}$, as shown in the dup. question. As it asks to prove the equivalent of $n=1$ there, this shows $n+1=2$ is a power of $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $n+1$ is not a power of $2$. Then $n+1$ can be written $n+1 = kl$, where $k$ is an odd integer at least $3$. So on the one hand, $\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p^l-1}=\frac{p^{kl}-1}{p^l-1}$ is an integer, and on the other hand, as $p-1$ divides $p^l-1$, it follows that $\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p^l-1}$ divides $\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}$. So to show that $\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}$ cannot be a power of $2$ for $n+1$ as above, it suffices to show that $\frac{p^{kl}-1}{p^l-1}$ is an odd integer at least $3$ [make sure you see why]. But then for such $n+1$:

$$\frac{p^{lk}-1}{p^l-1}$$  $$= 1 + p^l + p^{2l} + \ldots +p^{(k-1)l}.$$
As the RHS is the sum of an odd number $k \ge 3$ of terms, it follows that $\frac{p^{lk}-1}{p^l-1}$ is indeed an odd integer at least $3$ for such $n+1$. So as noted above, this implies that $\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}$ cannot be a power of $2$ for such $n+1$, and so the result follows.